# post-redirect-get with notification about update

Tags: model-view-controller, http, web-applications, post-redirect-get

We usually follow the convention of doing a redirect after every post, which is ideally very clean. But usually there is a requirement to give the user feedback about what has been updated.

When i do a post followed by get i wanna show the same page with the notification about the updation being done, which makes the GET very clumsy with the extra status of whats being updated. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Could you use session variables?

Comment: It would create load balancing problems. Sticky sessions are scary

Answer (score 0):

> which is ideally very clean

debatable.

> which makes the GET very clumsy with the extra status of whats being updated

...and that's one of the main reasons why.

Trying to pass transactional data via the session is a very bad practice.

The solution I've used is to use a front controller for sequences of forms (not a front controller for the whole site!) but in general trying to avoid the scenario where there is a sequence of forms to be posted

Comment: I dont get what you meant by front controller. Can you please?